# Swift: Change UITextField Value from inside NSItemProvider

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I've been battling this one all day, as you can see I'm new to Swift.

I'm trying to update a UITextField in a iOS Action Extension. Correct value logs below, and outside of the loadItem() the correct value can be set.

Weak variable in the outlet? Some sort of closure thing? Function fires asynchronously and I'm not allowed to update the UI this way once it finishes?

Thank you in advance!

```
class ActionViewController: UIViewController {

    //outlets
    @IBOutlet weak var bookmarkTitle: UITextField!

    //vars
    var pageTitle = ""



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


         if let inputItem = extensionContext!.inputItems.first as? NSExtensionItem {
             if let itemProvider = inputItem.attachments?.first as? NSItemProvider {
                 itemProvider.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: kUTTypePropertyList as String) { [unowned self] (dict, error) in
                    // do stuff!
                    let itemDictionary = dict as! NSDictionary
                    let javaScriptValues = itemDictionary[NSExtensionJavaScriptPreprocessingResultsKey] as! NSDictionary
                    print(javaScriptValues)
                    //this works, gets correct data. how to assign to IBOutlet?
                    self.pageTitle = javaScriptValues["title"] as! String
                    NSLog("Title From JS Preprocessor: " + self.pageTitle)

                    /*===================================*/
                    //Reference to property 'bookmarkTitle' in closure requires explicit 'self.' to make capture semantics explicit
                        //bookmarkTitle.text = self.pageTitle

                    //when the line below is used, the action extension fails to even open
                    self.bookmarkTitle.text = self.pageTitle
                    /*===================================*/

                }
             }
         }
    }

}
```

Comment: try to change the textfield text in Main Queue like this:
    
    
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    // work that impacts the user interface
self.bookmarkTitle.text = self.pageTitle
}

Comment: @TaimoorSuleman Thank you so very much!!! It worked like a charm. Put your comment as the answer if you want, and I'll mark it as answered correctly. It could have taken me days to figure that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to change the textfield text in Main Queue like this:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async { 
// work that impacts the user interface 
self.bookmarkTitle.text = self.pageTitle 
}
```